# A real-time (causal, non-symmetric) lowpass FIR filter with minimal passband ripple and phase

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, lowpass-filter, digital-filters

I am looking for a lowpass FIR filter that is causal (all samples used are current or past) and exhibits very low passband ripple and has passband phase very close to zero, which necessitates a filter to be a nonlinear-phase filter. Meanwhile, for transition band and stopband, I want frequency response of the filter to remain below 1.

I tried hard to look at some design mechanisms or principles in use but so far came up empty. Maximally flat nonlinear-phase FIR filters seem to exhibit excessive transition band overshoots beyond magnitude of 1.

So what design mechanism should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a minimum phase filter, which will have the least delay for a given magnitude response. The following response by MattL at the first post below details this further in using 'Leja Ordering' for converting large linear phase filter to a minimum phase filter using widely available algorithms (such as `firls` and `firpm` in MATLAB and `firls` and `remez` in Octave and Python scipy.signal). For filters of modest length it is fairly trivial to determine the zero locations for the linear phase filter and convert to a minimum phase filter by reflecting all the zeros to be inside the unit circle as detailed in the second post.

[Minimum Phase - All Pass Decomposition For Large Linear Phase Filters](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79410/minimum-phase-all-pass-decomposition-for-large-linear-phase-filters)

[Minimum phase FIR method](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25515/minimum-phase-fir-method)